# Exchange Migration without outlook configuration

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook

I am working on migrating some users from Exchange1 and Domain1 users to Exchange2 and Domain2.

I am able to migrate their accounts from Domain1 to Domain2 with their current password. No issues.

I am able to migrate their mailbox from Exchange1 to Exchange2 while linking to their new Exchange2 mailbox.

I can now login to the new Exchange2 mailbox by OWA using Domain2\user and their existing password everything is there no problem.

I then update the autodiscover in my dns to point to Exchange2.

My problem is none of the Outlook clients connect at this point. When opening Outlook all I get is "Disconnected" at the lower right, no prompt to enter a password, nothing. If I remove the account from Outlook and configure it again it works properly.

Is there something I can do to save our team of reconfiguring 300 plus Outlook clients?

Comment: How did you migrate their mailboxes? What is the state of the source mailbox?

Comment: I used CodeTwo Exchange Migration tool. The source mailbox is still available, but not reachable to the clients because of the DNS change. if I revert the DNS to point to the Exchange1 Outlook works again.

Comment: Ah. CodeTwo. Very familiar with it. **If after the migration Outlook doesn't connect to your new mail server, you also need to create a new Outlook profile and set it as the default one for each mailbox user.** - The same issue is applicable to all three CodeTwo mailbox migration types. - https://www.codetwo.com/userguide/exchange-migration/cutover-migration.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please perform the following inspections to narrow down this issue(Outlook disconnected):

1. Did you encounter this issue on an internal/external client or both of them?
2. Perform a **[Test E-mail AutoConfiguration](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/2150)** in Outlook and see if the **`Results`** panel returns the correct URLs and the autodiscover query is successful in **`Log`** panel.
3. For external clients, you could perform an Outlook connectivity test via **[Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Ola/input)** and see if there is any error.

Besides, the following guidance about the error after migrating Exchange mailboxes are for your reference, check if it works after restarting the **Autodiscover Application Pool** in IIS: **[Outlook logon fails after mailbox moves from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013 or Exchange 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/outlook-logon-fails-after-mailbox-moves-from-exchange-2010-to-exchange-2013-or-exchange-2016-bd3f59ed-c521-4349-5c00-c49717b5e04d)**